# How to get test execution video of karate ui test

Tags: karate

How to configure the video recording capability using config.js for karate ui test

I have tried to add videoFile property with path to record the video in config.js but video was not recorded.
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'chromedriver', executable: 'src/test/java/examples/users/chromedriver.exe', videoFile: 'src/test/java/examples/users/videos' });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that simple and requires you to do some research. It is expected to be easy if you use the Karate Docker container and `chrome` (native) as the driver `type`. You can find more details here:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-chrome

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64591351/143475